# how to detect click on right vs left half of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if a click occured on the right or left half of the `.targ` element?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.targ', function(e) {
  let targ = $(this);
  let center = targ.width() / 2;
  let x = '???'; // here I need clicked PositionX relative to targ
  if (x > center) {
    console.log('clicked right');
  } else {
    console.log('clicked left');
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}

.targ {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='targ'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the X and Y coordinates of the click location within the element from the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties on the event which is provided to the event handler. Then you can compare it to your calculated centre point. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.targ', function(e) {
  let center = $(this).width() / 2;
  if (e.offsetX > center) {
    console.log('clicked right');
  } else {
    console.log('clicked left');
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}

.targ {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="targ">LOREM IPSUM</div>
</div>
```